# Windows Forms: Obtain window size to fit a picture box containing an image

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, window, picturebox

I have a `Form` that consists of a `Panel` (anchored to all four sides) containing a `PictureBox` (also anchored to all four sides of the `Panel`), with a `Label` above the `Panel`.  The `Panel` has `AutoScroll` set to true and the `PictureBox` contains an unscaled image and has `SizeMode` set to `AutoSize`, so the image is never rescaled and scroll bars auto-appear if the `PictureBox`/`Form` size doesn't allow for the entire image (as I want).

Question: **How do I determine the initial window size in the Form's Load event handler so that the window will exactly fit the image, with no scroll bars in the PictureBox?**  The Image property of the PictureBox was already set in the contructor.

I would then (if the window isn't too big) set the initial window size to that size, and constrain the window resizing to a maximum of that size.

Many thanks.

Comment: In what constructor exactly? How are you loading the image? On form load?

Comment: Sorry, on Form load event - updating question.  Thanks.

Comment: Simply set the form's AutoSize property to True so it will automatically grow to try to accommodate the auto-sized picturebox.

Comment: That's a good idea. Although, you would need a way to determine if it's too big. Maximum size would fix that. Post an answer and I'll up-vote it.

Comment: Arg - I forgot that the PictureBox is in a Panel with AutoScroll (how I get the scroll bars automatically).  Testing with AutoSize set in the Panel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Passant's comment and KoBE's answer both combined to produce the answer I used:

I set the `Panel`'s and the `Form`'s `AutoSize` to true in the Designer.  This causes the `Panel`, and then the `Form` to be sized before load so that the entire image fits in the window.  Then in the `Load` event handler, I have the following code:

```
    this.MaximumSize = this.Size;

    ... code to make sure MaximumSize isn't larger than the screen ...

    // Turn off autosize so the user can shrink the window.
    // Note: Changing AutoSize instantly changes the window size!
    c_picturePanel.AutoSize = false;
    this.AutoSize = false;

    // Restore the window size.
    this.Size = this.MaximumSize;
```

This produces a window that is the appropriate size for the form, won't grow too large, and auto uses scroll bars if the window is shrunk by the user.

Many thanks to KoBE and Hans Passant.

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting a MaximumSize in the designer, then do this check on form load:

```
Image i = Image.FromFile("");

if (i.Width > this.MaximumSize.Width)
    this.Width = MaximumSize.Width;
else
    this.Width = i.Width;

if (i.Height > this.MaximumSize.Height)
    this.Height = MaximumSize.Height;
else
    this.Height = i.Height;

pbImage.Image = i;
```

If you don't know what you want the maximum size to be, then you can base it off the Screen size using:

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
```

Edit:

As Hans Passant pointed out in the comments: "Simply set the form's AutoSize property to True so it will automatically grow to try to accommodate the auto-sized picturebox"

This along with setting the MaximumSize of the form should work for you.